# Apostrophes in jquery/javascript string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code which appends an icon with an alert after the `<a>` tag :

```
$j("li[name='"+node_name+"'] > a").after('<a onmouseover="alert(\' expnote_from_db[n][0] \');" ><ins class="' + selected_class + '">&nbsp;</ins></a>');
```

The code above works fine except that it displays `exp_from_db[n][0]` as a string inside the alert box.

So I changed it to the code below but nothing is displayed now

```
  $j("li[name='"+node_name+"'] > a").after('<a onmouseover="alert(\'"'+ expnote_from_db[n][0] + '"\');" ><ins class="' + selected_class + '">&nbsp;</ins></a>');
```

I don't understand where did I go wrong with the apostrophes.

I would appreciate your help regarding this. Thanks

Comment: `"alert(\' expnote_from_db[n][0] \');"` should look like `"alert(\'' + expnote_from_db[n][0] + '\');"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work

```
$j('li[name="'+node_name+'"] > a')
    .after('<a onmouseover="alert(\''+ expnote_from_db[n][0] + '\')" ><ins class="' + selected_class + '">&nbsp;</ins></a>');
```

Answer (score 3):

The `"` characters are delimiting the HTML attribute. You are terminating that attribute prematurely.

```
<a onmouseover="alert(\'"
```

Nesting JavaScript in HTML attributes is a pain.

Nesting JavaScript in HTML attributes in JavaScript strings is a bigger pain.

Don't do it. Apply event handlers using `addEventListener` and friends (since you are using jQuery that means using the [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method which abstracts them).